# React/JS toggle table columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a table in React and need to have a select status on a column when clicking the top cell and being able to toggle that between the columns.

At this stage I roughly put together something like this:

```
const types = {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
}

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onOneClick = this.onClick.bind(this, types.one)
    this.onTwoClick = this.onClick.bind(this, types.two)
  }

  onClick = column => {
    this.props.onColumnChange(column)
  }

  render() {
    const { column } = this.props
    const classOne = classnames(styles.one, column === types.one ? styles.active : null)
    const classTwo = classnames(styles.two, column === types.two ? styles.active : null)
    return (
      <section className={styles.columnSelection}>
        <table className={styles.columns}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Select column</th>
              <td className={classOne} onClick={this.onOneClick}>one</td>
              <td className={classTwo} onClick={this.onTwoClick}>two</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <td className={classOne}>one</td>
              <td className={classTwo}>two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <td className={classOne}>one</td>
              <td className={classTwo}>two</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

Test.propTypes = {
  column: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.values(types)),
  onColumnChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

I think this will probably achieve what I want but wondering if there are better ways to do that? also I don't think there is any `nth-child` selector like in jQuery to help me. There are few different reasons on why I need the table, so I'm not looking to change the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a css style for '.active' for highlighting the selected column and change the above code like,

```
 class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    state={
        activeColumn : 0
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <section className={styles.columnSelection}>
        <table className={styles.columns}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Select column</th>
              <td className={this.state.activeColumn===1 ? "active":"" } onClick={()=>this.setState({activeColumn:1})}>one</td>
              <td className={this.state.activeColumn===2 ? "active":"" } onClick={()=>this.setState({activeColumn:2})}>two</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <td className={this.state.activeColumn===1 ? "active":"" }>one</td>
              <td className={this.state.activeColumn===2 ? "active":"" }>two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <td className={this.state.activeColumn===1 ? "active":"" }>one</td>
              <td className={this.state.activeColumn===2 ? "active":"" }>two</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing it wrong. In `React` you need to use `state` in order to maintain the component state. And on `click` or any other event, you actually updated that component state value. The state is usually initialized in `constructor` like `this.state={columns: 'one'}`

Then in `render()` method, you are using that state using `this.state.columns` to check and render or output any expression or you then output any JSX/HTML. You can use ternary operation e.g. `(this.state.columns=='two' ? 'It is two column' : 'its one column)`.

Inside your `onclick` or any event handler you update the state of the component using `this.setState()`.

For more details check this guide: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-react-js-in-5-minutes-526472d292f4

I would really recommend that you first go through its documentation and examples before doing real codding.